# Regex is misinterpreted

Tags: regex, delphi

In my unit test, the URL http: //www.test.c is accepted, but it should provide an error. The code is used in Delphi.

```
kRgEx := TRegEx.Create
('((https|http):\/\/)?(((?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+)|(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(:\d{1,})?)).*');
```

Answer (score 1):

It matches `ww.test.c` because `ww.` evaluates TRUE for the `(?!www)` part: yes, it is *not* a `www`.

A more appropriate pattern (still not accepting all valid addresses and disregarding IPv4 addresses) would be: `^(https?:\/\/|www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}` (matches right from the start and respects the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle).